# Does the frontend HTTP request have to match the backend HTTP request, eg: axios.patch and express router.patch

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, frontend

I have google searched, don't seem to find an answer to this. What is the difference between them, doing axios.patch(url) and then the express router router.patch(url).

Comment: Is you question that the request method should match? if so, yes. Is your question that the request route should match? Then also yes... I suggest you read how http rq

Comment: "What is the difference between them, doing axios.patch(url) and then the express router router.patch(url)" axios (client) sends the request, router (server) receives the request and then responds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Whatever HTTP method you're specifying in your request should match whatever your backend expects to receive.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).